# SQL query writing help - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am not a proficient SQL query writer. I can handle a few table joins. Pretty novice. Seek some advise and help.

- DB = Postgres
- This looks trivial, but, I am unaware of how to proceed this with the fastest execution
- Probably I can engage PL/pgSQL?
- Employee table has updward of 100K rows and CrossRef table has around 50k rows
- Similar to Employee table, there are other tables where EMPID is referenced. Even they need to be updated. But, I believe that is something that can be replicated once I have it ready for one table

Sample data

### CrossRef (Table)

```
+-----+-----+
|OldID|NewID|
+-----+-----+
|A1   |A1   |
+-----+-----+
|A2   |B2   |
+-----+-----+
|A4   |A4   |
+-----+-----+
|A5   |B5   |
+-----+-----+
```

### Employee (Table)

```
+-----+
|EmpID|
+-----+
|A1   |
+-----+
|A1   |
+-----+
|A2   |
+-----+
|A2   |
+-----+
|A3   |
+-----+
|A3   |
+-----+
```

### To achieve

```
If CrossRef.OldID=Employee.EmpID THEN
    Set Employee.EmpID=CrossRef.NewID
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `UPDATE ... FROM` should suffice for this:

```
UPDATE Employee AS e
SET EmpId = c.NewID
FROM CrossRef AS c
WHERE e.EmpID = c.OldID
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/142b2/2)

Comment: OMG. What was I thinking? This is seriously easy. Thanks @PinnyM. I will run the same over in production tomorrow and share updates. Turns out, I think too much for a simple problem!